# Sort List<T> Property every time an item is added

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a List in a class that I have as a property:

```
public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
```

Data will be added to this list and eventually the data will be read. When the data is read, it will be read like:

```
foreach(string str in my_obj.MyList)
{
   // do something
}
```

I could, of course, do:

```
foreach(string str in my_obj.MyList.Sort())
{
   // do something
}
```

but since this is a class library I do not want the use to have to do anything. I also do not want the user to have to call a `Sort()` method within the class. What I would ideally have is the list being sorted every time an item is added or when it is read.

Comment: You could just subclass `List<T>` and override `Add` and sort after an item is added - there may also be a `SortedList<T>` implementation

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx - you would need to provide the strings as both key/value

Comment: @Charleh: That would be `SortedList<K,V>`.

Comment: You can also use HashSet instead of List

Comment: @ŁukaszKosiak: a `HashSet<T>` is not sorted at all.

Comment: @PatrickHofman not really: "This method is an O(n) operation for unsorted data, where n is Count. It is an O(log n) operation if the new element is added at the end of the list. If insertion causes a resize, the operation is O(n)." So, adding new element at the and is O(log n) - not very expensive :) (but still O(n) in other cases);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your property like this, use a backing field and sort it in the *getter* method before you return the list to the caller:

```
private List<string> _myList; 
public List<string> MyList
{
   get { _myList.Sort(); return _myList; }
   set { _myList = value; }
}
```

Ofcourse this will perform sorting when you attempt to add new item to your list like `myobj.MyList.Add("foo");` to avoid this you can add another method e.g. `AddToMyList` and use `_myList.Add` instead.And also change the property type `IEnumerable<string>` to prevent the user from adding new items directly.

Comment: This solution has too many downsides. It will sort every time the list is accessed, which is a waste, and it will not be sorted properly when items are added after somebody got a reference to the list. As it is anybody which gets the list can add items to it, so the order could be corrupted easily.

Answer (score 0):

Handle adds via an add method in your class. Doesn't protect against direct access of the list but you can insert the item into the correct index of your list based upon your sort requirements.

This approach saves you resorting your list as a single hit.

Just another idea to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such collection with ObservableCollection Class

Refer URL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicates in you list you should use [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) It's a set, so it can't contain the same object twice (but how would you sort objects which are the same?), but otherwise it does exactly what you need.

You could also consider implementing [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) in the class which contains the list, that would allow you to simple do `foreach(string str in my_obj)` You can then make the list private and sort it once after all objects are added. Right now each user which gets the list can also change it, remove items etc. Which may not be what you want.

The implementation can be as simple as this:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public MyClass()
    {
        // Fill myList...
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Linq namespace, after you add `using System.Linq` then you should be able to do following

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list = list.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();
```

OR if you want to sort ascending order

```
list = list.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

If you call those methods after adding item. Your list will be sorted.

Comment: Or better yet, just use [List<T>.Sort() instead of OrderBy()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056118/utility-of-listt-sort-versus-listt-orderby-for-a-member-of-a-custom-cont)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to go with SortedList ??
I guess thats exactly what you are looking for. You can just ignore the value of "short" in SortedList or just provide some default value. Or may be you can find some means to utilize field too.

Comment: As you said, it has to be sorted on every insert, the code should be like this:                                                               private List<string> _myList; 
public List<string> MyList
{
   get { return _myList; }
   set { _myList = value; _myList = _myList.Sort(); }
}